# Paginated report from a deneb visual

Tags: vega-lite, vega, reportbuilder3.0, deneb, powerbi-paginated-reports

I developed a **Gantt Chart** using **deneb (Vega-Lite)** which uses a scroll bar due to an important number of rows. However I need the report containing this visual to be exported into a **paginated PDF** that allows to see all the records properly.

The problem is that the Gantt Chart has very specific features that **can't be replicated in a PBI Paginated Report**.

Is there any other solution to obtain a multipage pdf from a deneb visual or anything similar?

Comment: Could you add multiple Deneb charts and add a filter transform to each chart?

Comment: If you can use Deneb-Lite, I believe it can be exported to PDF. You might have to expand your PBI canvas/page size so that everything is visible.